# Google App engine (Python) - Contact Us info from an anonymous user

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How to allow someone without credentials to send me an email using the contactus form that I have provided on my Google app engine app?? When I am trying normally using mail modules, it is saying no real mail is bieng sent. Help me fix it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, All you need is to get an alert about the "Contact us form submission activity" by a visitor (anonymous user) on the website.

You can implement it by having an email id like contact@example.com and send email to itself when a user submits the form. You can do it pretty easily, as there are lots of examples over the Internet to do this.

I am not a Python guy, so I cannot help you with the source code.
Hope it will help you somehow.